# Some weird problem with fuzzy query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I have one doc in es

```
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "109487",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "id": "109487",
          "title": "Interstellar",
          "year": 2014,
          "genre": [
            "Sci-Fi",
            "IMAX"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          "Interstellar"
        ]
      }
```

I am searching with a fuzzy query like

```
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "title": {"value": "intersteller", "fuzziness": 1}
        }
    }
}
```

But the weird thing is if i am searching with small i in `intersteller` then i am getting the desired record with title as `Interstellar` but if i am searching with Capital `I` ie if my query is

```
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "title": {"value": "Intersteller", "fuzziness": 1}
        }
    }
}
```

then am not getting and docs from db .. just wanted to understand what is happening behind the scenes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***The fuzzy query does not analyze the text. Mostly fuzzy query acts like a term query itself.***

In your case `"title"` field must be using [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html). So `"Intersteller"` is indexed as `"intersteller"`. Now when you are performing a fuzzy query on `"intersteller"`, you will get the result but not with `"Intersteller"`

To know more about fuzzy query refer to this [elasticsearch blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-fuzzy-search#the-different-types-of-fuzzy-searches)

---

**It is better to use a [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) along with the fuzziness parameter**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "Intersteller",
        "fuzziness": "auto"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you want use fuzzy query, then you need to increase the [fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness) parameter, to get your document to match

```
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "title": {
        "value": "Intersteller",
        "fuzziness": 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: understood Thanks :-)  @ESCoder